# django creating signals at runtime

Tags: django

I've been trying to work on a way to handle creation of signals at runtime, I came up with the following code which reads from a configuration/table and registers post_save connection

```
def _send_to_messaging_notify(**kwargs):
    """ _send_to_messaging_notify
    """
    if kwargs.get('created'):
        instance = kwargs.get('instance')
        ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance)
        notify.apply_async(args=[instance.pk, ct.pk, kwargs.get('when')])


def create_function(name, args):
    def y(**kwargs):
        kwargs.update({'when': inspect.stack()[0][3]})
        print 'signal executed on {0}'.format(kwargs.get('sender'))
        _send_to_messaging_notify(**kwargs)

    y_code = types.CodeType(args, \
                            y.func_code.co_nlocals, \
                            y.func_code.co_stacksize, \
                            y.func_code.co_flags, \
                            y.func_code.co_code, \
                            y.func_code.co_consts, \
                            y.func_code.co_names, \
                            y.func_code.co_varnames, \
                            y.func_code.co_filename, \
                            name, \
                            y.func_code.co_firstlineno, \
                            y.func_code.co_lnotab)

    return types.FunctionType(y_code, y.func_globals, name)


def load_signals():
    """ load_signals
    """
    from default_senders import senders
    #
    for k in senders.iterkeys():
        post_save.connect(create_function(str(k), 0), sender=load_model(senders[k].get('default_content_type')),
                          dispatch_uid=k)


load_signals()
```

create_function is to create the signal handler at runtime, then it is called with `post_save.connect`

when I try to execute this

```
myfunc = create_function(str(k), 0)
myfunc(sender='xxx')
```

it works fine, but when hooked to post_save.connect it does nothing when targeted model received post_save operation.. any ideas this is happening? can any one advise please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see where you are creating the signal **post_save** and sending the signal in your code.In **load_signals()** , include the following lines of code at the beginning

```
from django.dispatch import Signal
post_save = Signal(providing_args=['arg1', 'arg2'])
```

Then you could connect the signal in the for loop to the receiver function using

```
post_save.connect(create_function(str(k), 0))
```

and send the signal using

```
 post_save.send(sender='a_cool_sender', arg1='Hello!', arg2=1)
```

The best article that I found online which clearly explains Django signals is [here](http://www.shutupandship.com/2012/04/django-signals-and-observer-design.html).